# Xaml, wpf image position and crop issue

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-runtime, crop, resize-crop

I have images of 600px width and 600px height. we have three sizes of circles. all have the center in the middle. Some have reflection as shadow beneath it. I would like to crop the image for display purposes.
[image: largest circle]

So the largest circle as shown above has a diameter of about 500 pixels, but the medium and small ones have less. I know in the code which size I have of object type `Product`. Because of the size differences I have to place them differently and used three placeholder images for it, like this:

```
<Image x:Name="imgCoinHolderSmall"      
       HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
       Margin="0,495,0,0" 
       VerticalAlignment="Top" 
       Stretch="Fill" 
       Width="200" 
       Height="200"/>
<Image x:Name="imgCoinHolderMedium"     
       HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
       Margin="0,510,0,0" 
       VerticalAlignment="Top" 
       Stretch="Fill" 
       Width="200" 
       Height="200"/>
<Image x:Name="imgCoinHolderLarge"      
       HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
       Margin="0,520,0,0" 
       VerticalAlignment="Top" 
       Stretch="Fill" 
       Width="200" 
       Height="200"/>
```

So can I change the properties of the image such that it does not display the red part of this screenshot:
[image]
By the way, I do not display the images on their original size (as you can see at the xaml code) I set the width to 200. It is just a display thing, I do not have to store the new image. I would like to do it on the fly, preferably by setting image properties in the xaml. (for all three sizes of circles)

Is using the `CroppedBitmap` the best approach? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752345.aspx it is for windows rt by the way.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One option would be to use a [clipping mask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.clip%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
<Image Source="MyImage.jpg">
    <Image.Clip>
        <RectangleGeometry Rect="10,10,80,80"></RectangleGeometry>
    </Image.Clip>
</Image>
```

The [rect structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.rect%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) takes X,Y, Width and Height values that you have to set depending on your image.

Comment: Thanks that is exactly what I was looking for. The `croppedbitmap` is unavailable for windows rt

Comment: I am rather new to xaml and wpf, can you give me a few pointers to select good values for the rect? Should I use blend for it?

Comment: I edited my answer, you will have to do some calculations to get the correct values for the rect. Remember that in WPF the 0,0 Point is the upper left corner.