# XAML equivalent to object-position from CSS

Tags: c#, wpf, css, xaml

I'm working on a WPF app which displays a list of items and each one has a small image associated with it. From the API I receive the image url and a focus point represented by two numbers between 0-1.
The web app just multiplies those numbers with 100 and sets the object-position CSS property with them like this:

```
focusPoints: 0.9/0.5
```

becomes

```
object-position: 90% 50%;
```

My question is how do I use this in WPF? There's no property similar to object-position and although I thought that I just have to use Margin it appears that it's not that simple.
I'll give you an example. Let's say that I have a picture of a human face, but the face is not centered on the image, it's actually in the right side. If I crop the image, then the face will be cropped, but if I set a focus point on the face, the image will be cropped from the left side instead of cutting from each edge. That's how the focus point is used and in CSS you just use object-position, but in XAML I think I have to do some math in order to figure out what is the Margin or Canvas.Top/Left.
Also, [here's a demo](http://recordit.co/24P3Uk27GP) of how you can set a focus point in the image.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. If you want to explicitly position an element using coordinates, you should use a Canvas: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Positioning the element is not the problem, implementing the focus point is the problem.

Comment: Focus point? Please be more specific.

Comment: Sorry, I edited my question with an example.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for the Clip property? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21931777/xaml-wpf-image-position-and-crop-issue

Comment: Thank you but no, it's not the same as object-position.

Comment: There is no such thing as "object-position" in XAML.

Comment: So your image is bigger than content box you are fitting it to?

Comment: It's definitely bigger, but until now I would set Stretch property to Fill. This is a new type of icon in our product called "cover image", and they want to be positioned according to that focal point, but I need someone who knows CSS to tell me exactly how object-position works. I think I'll close this question and open another one just for this.
@mm8 I know, that's why I'm asking if anyone knows something similar :)

Comment: Well your question is clear for those who know (or care to figure out) what css object-position is, so I don't think it should be closed. Yes, there is no such thing in wpf but maybe someone will show how to write a custom panel or attached property or something else to achieve similar behavior.

Comment: By the way I'm not sure why you cannot use Clip indeed, you basically need to crop region with size of your bounding box around your focal point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### How CSS object-position works

It compares width/height of img html element with width/height of the actual picture. The difference of those is considered a "100%". So if the container (img element) is 100px wide and the picture is 160px wide, the difference is 60px and that is a "100%". If we set horizontal object-position value to 50%, it will move the picture 30px (50% of 60px) to the left within the container, effectively centering the picture horizontally.

#### WPF Control

Custom control that manipulates an image within a canvas.

```
[TemplatePart(Name = ImagePart, Type = typeof(Image))]
[TemplatePart(Name = CanvasPart, Type = typeof(Canvas))]
public class PositionableImage : Control
{
    private const string ImagePart = "PART_Image";
    private const string CanvasPart = "PART_Canvas";

    static PositionableImage()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(
            typeof(PositionableImage),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(PositionableImage)));
    }

    public string Source
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(SourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SourceProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Source",
        typeof(string),
        typeof(PositionableImage),
        new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty));

    public double HorizontalPosition
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(HorizontalPositionProperty); }
        set { SetValue(HorizontalPositionProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty HorizontalPositionProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "HorizontalPosition",
        typeof(double),
        typeof(PositionableImage),
        new PropertyMetadata(0d, OnHorizontalPositionChanged));

    private static void OnHorizontalPositionChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        PositionableImage pi = d as PositionableImage;
        if (pi == null) return;

        if (!double.TryParse(e.NewValue.ToString(), out double newPosition)) return;

        pi.UpadateHorizontalPosition(newPosition);
    }

    public double VerticalPosition
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(VerticalPositionProperty); }
        set { SetValue(VerticalPositionProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty VerticalPositionProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "VerticalPosition",
        typeof(double),
        typeof(PositionableImage),
        new PropertyMetadata(0d, OnVerticalPositionSizeChanged));

    private static void OnVerticalPositionSizeChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        PositionableImage pi = d as PositionableImage;
        if (pi == null) return;

        if (!double.TryParse(e.NewValue.ToString(), out double newPosition)) return;

        pi.UpdateVerticalPosition(newPosition);
    }

    private Image image;
    private Canvas canvas;

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();

        if (this.canvas != null)
            this.canvas.SizeChanged -= OnCanvasSizeChanged;

        this.image = this.GetTemplateChild(ImagePart) as Image;
        this.canvas = this.GetTemplateChild(CanvasPart) as Canvas;

        if (this.canvas != null)
            this.canvas.SizeChanged += OnCanvasSizeChanged;
    }

    private void OnCanvasSizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.HeightChanged)
            this.UpdateVerticalPosition(VerticalPosition);

        if (e.WidthChanged)
            this.UpadateHorizontalPosition(HorizontalPosition);
    }

    private void UpadateHorizontalPosition(double position)
    {
        if (this.image == null || this.canvas == null) return;

        double offset = this.CalculateOffset(this.canvas.ActualWidth, this.image.ActualWidth, position);

        this.image.SetCurrentValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, offset);
    }

    private void UpdateVerticalPosition(double position)
    {
        if (this.image == null || this.canvas == null) return;

        double offset = this.CalculateOffset(this.canvas.ActualHeight, this.image.ActualHeight, position);

        this.image.SetCurrentValue(Canvas.TopProperty, offset);
    }

    private double CalculateOffset(double canvasLength, double imageLength, double position)
    {
        return -(imageLength - canvasLength) * position;
    }
}
```

Template

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:PositionableImage}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:PositionableImage}">
                <Canvas x:Name="PART_Canvas"
                        Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"
                        Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        ClipToBounds="True">
                    <Image x:Name="PART_Image"
                           Source="{Binding Path=Source, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                </Canvas>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Usage

```
<local:PositionableImage Width="60"
                         Height="60"
                         Source="H:\test.jpg"
                         HorizontalPosition=".5"
                         VerticalPosition=".5"/>
```

In use

[image: example image]

Comment: Explaining how object-position works was enough, but thank you very much for the source code, it did exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @thewindev You're welcome. I've got background in web development, so it was fun marrying the two.